# How to run animation only once while current session?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, anime.js

I have a website page that uses `react-anime` and `react-typing-animation`. My issue is to animate some elements displayed on it only once while the current session. So, if my site was opened on the main page, the animation would launch, and then, after switching a few pages and returning back to the main page, the animation wouldn't be executed again.

I've thought about `sessionStorage`, but I don't understand how to use it with these libraries.

Here's all the code:

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from './Index.module.css'
import Greeting from '../components/main/Greeting'
import Yelnya from '../components/main/Yelnya/Yelnya'
import BlueLakes from '../components/main/BlueLakes'
import Gallery from "../components/main/Gallery";


export default function Home() {
    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <Greeting />
            <Yelnya />
            <BlueLakes />
            <Gallery />
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Greeting.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from './Greeting.module.css'
import Tag from './Tag'
import Anime from "react-anime";
import Typing from "react-typing-animation"


export default function Greeting() {
    return (
        <div className={styles.root}>
            <div className={styles.title}>
                <Typing startDelay={50} speed={100}>
                    Explore Belarusian nature with us.
                </Typing>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.hint}>
                <Anime
                    opacity={[0,1]}
                    translateX={[-50,0]}
                    duration={3000}
                    delay={4200}
                >
                    <p className={styles.hintTitle}>Go to:</p>
                </Anime>
                <Tag title="#Yelnya" link="/#yelnya" delay={4400}/>
                <Tag title="#Blue lakes" link="/#blue-lakes" delay={4500}/>
                <Tag title="#Galleries" link="/#galleries" delay={4600}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Tag.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from './Tag.module.css'
import Link from 'next/link'
import Anime from "react-anime";


export default function Tag({ title, link, delay }) {
    return (
        <Anime
            opacity={[0,1]}
            translateY={[50,0]}
            duration={3000}
            delay={delay}
        >
            <Link href={link}>
                <div className={styles.tag}>
                    <p className={styles.text}>{title}</p>
                </div>
            </Link>
        </Anime>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made an example for using LocalStorage and handle animation with them

```
export default function App() {
  const animated = !!localStorage.getItem("animated");

  if (animated === false) {
    localStorage.setItem("animated", true);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {!animated && (
        <Anime
          opacity={[0, 1]}
          translateX={[-50, 0]}
          duration={3000}
          delay={500}
        >
          <p>Go to:</p>
        </Anime>
      )}
      {animated && <p>Go to:</p>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

also you can test it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-cdn-vc34g)